# Python config files with arguments

Tags: python, config

I am using a python config file. (Specifically it is a logging dictionary file in YAML format). It defines a value as

```
handlers:  
  fileHandler:    
    class: logging.FileHandler   
    filename: a.txt
    mode: w    
    formatter: damiFormatter
    level: ERROR
```

I was wondering if I could set the filename dynamically. I.e. read it from another config file? I can do this in the code - use ConfigParser to read a value and then set it as

```
configValues=ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser().read(configFile)
fName=configValues.get("NAMES","fileName")

dict=yaml.load(open('logging.config', 'r'))       
dict['handlers']['fileHandler']['filename']=fName
```

But I was wondering if there is a simpler way, an argument that could be passed to the dictionary config file?

I think I can do it using defaults, but was wondering if there is a cleaner implementation

Thanks very much.

Comment: If your current approach works well and is transparent for the end user, you may be over-thinking. Done is better than perfect, just GTD!!! :-)

Comment: Thanks Paulo. The thing is, I wanted to separate out all the config variable definitions into another file - so not reference the handler names in the main code etc. But I guess I will have to use this approach after all.